# i have created a weighted graph and using algorithm to find shortest path but there is a issue in it?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have created a weighted graph and it is being created properly and the shortest path algorithm is also correct. the only issue is that when i am trying to store the shortest path between node in a vector. I have used recursive function to store in vector so there it shows that it is getting stored in vector but finally when I take the size of vector in main function it gives one only. so i unable to find where issue lies. can anyone help to find error. i even tried debugging but didn't found error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::make_pair;
using std::pair;
using std::vector;

void addedge(vector<pair<int,int>> adj[],int u,int v,int wt)
{
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v,wt));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u,wt));
}

class Shorthistory{

public:
    int dest;
    int length;
    int previousnode;
};

void printshortgraph(vector<Shorthistory> vis)
{
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<vis.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<vis[i].dest<<" "<<vis[i].length<<" "<<vis[i].previousnode<<"\n";
    }
}

void shortestpath(vector<pair<int,int>>adjlist[],bool arr[],vector<Shorthistory> vis,int n)
{
    int len=-1;
    int prenode=-1;
    int currnode=-1;

    for(std::size_t i=0;i<vis.size();i++)
    {
        for(auto it=adjlist[vis[i].dest].begin();it!=adjlist[vis[i].dest].end();it++)
        {
            if(arr[it->first]==false)
            {
                //cout<<it->first<<" ";
                int len2=vis[i].length + it->second;
                if(len==-1)
                {
                    len=len2;
                    prenode=vis[i].dest;
                    currnode=it->first;

                }
                else if(len2<len)
                {
                    len=len2;
                    prenode=vis[i].dest;
                    currnode=it->first;

                }
            }
        }
        //cout<<"\n";
    }

    if(len!=-1)
    {
        arr[currnode]=true;
        //cout<<currnode<<"\n";
        vis.push_back({currnode,len,prenode});
        
        shortestpath(adjlist,arr,vis,n);
        
        //printshortgraph(vis);
    }
    else{
        printshortgraph(vis);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    vector<pair<int,int>> adjlst[n+1];

    while(m--)
    {
        int x,y,w;
        cin>>x>>y>>w;
        addedge(adjlst,x,y,w);
    }

    printgraph(adjlst,n+1);

    vector<Shorthistory> vis;
    bool fan[n+1];
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        fan[i]=false;
    }
    fan[1]=true;
    vis.push_back({1,0,1});
    shortestpath(adjlst,fan,vis,n);

    cout<<vis.size()<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output of my code

```
6 8
2 3 7
4 1 20
5 1 5
6 5 18
3 6 10
2 4 8
5 4 7
5 2 5
4 node, 20 weight
5 node, 5 weight
3 node, 7 weight
4 node, 8 weight
5 node, 5 weight
2 node, 7 weight
6 node, 10 weight
1 node, 20 weight
2 node, 8 weight
5 node, 7 weight
1 node, 5 weight
6 node, 18 weight
4 node, 7 weight
2 node, 5 weight
5 node, 18 weight
3 node, 10 weight
1 0 1
5 5 1
2 10 5
4 12 5
3 17 2
6 23 5
1
```

I think the error is with vector as I am passing it with value and not reference. is this the issue then how edge would be added as there also i am passing vector as value only. please help and explain a bit about it

Comment: `vector<pair<int,int>> adjlst[n+1];` and `bool fan[n+1];` is not valid C++. There are no variable-length arrays in C++. You should tag compiler-specific questions with the compiler you are using or completely avoid compiler-specific code.

Comment: You should enable and fix compiler warnings. Please provide a [mcve] with input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: In your code you are calling a `printgraph` but there is only a `printshortgraph` function with different parameters. Did you forget the `printgraph` function or is this a copy error? Instead of a class with all public members you could use a struct.

Comment: i have not added printgraph function because that was working fine. my question is that when i am passing vector to add edge using pushback function, the edge is getting added but when I am passing vector to add short path using pushback then it seems that within function the short path is getting added but in the main function, the size is still one. why it is behaving in such manner i am not getting that?? can you explain me this feature of  vector please

Comment: I'm asking for a [mcve] to debug it.